# ListView doesn't resize after rows become bigger loading images from asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview, android-listfragment

I have a `ListView` that is inside a `TabHost`.   There's a custom `CursorAdapter` to return 4 different views into the list.  One of the 4 types is an image pulled from either the SD or the assets folder.  Originally I had the image loading in from the `CursorAdapter` itself and this would cause the UI thread to hang while each image loaded so I moved the code to an `AsyncTask`.

This all works EXCEPT for the case where a very short list of items is returned.  When this happens, the `ListView` doesn't re-size after the images have loaded and you can only scroll in a tiny portion of the screen at the top.

I cannot figure out how to get get the `listView` to relayout.  Calling relayout and invalidate on the View itself doesn't work.  Trying to find the parent of the View returns null.  The default ListFragment layout already sets the height to "Match_Parent". Manually setting the layout in onCreateView to a layout with all heights set to "Match_Parent" doesn't fix it.  Passing in the adapter itself to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` just causes a loop and doesn't re-size the `ListView`.

Frustratingly, when I change tabs the view flashes up correctly just before the new tab is drawn over it.  Very occasionally when I rotate the device or flick between tabs it renders correctly, but most of the time it doesn't.

For debugging purposes I tried adding various relayout commands to onListItemClick and found that calling ListView.relayout() sometimes fixes the problem, but often doesn't.

[image] [image]

On the left is how it loads with the AsyncTask, on the right is how it loads with the main thread loader.  The content is there on the left but you have to scroll because the listview is incorrectly sized.

What am I missing?  Is there some way to get the `ListView` or the current tab or even the whole screen to redraw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is cause by the ImageView resizing after the ListView has been laid out.  Setting the ImageView's height and width to the dimensions of the image before spinning off the AsyncTask makes the ListView layout correctly.

My images are all local with the filenames etc in a db so I can get the correct dimensions prior to loading the image.  If you couldn't get the image dimensions ahead of time, I'm not 100% sure what you'd do.

Comment: I've found a similar problem, but where the item view was not correctly layouted, it used a RelativeLayout. Grouping the controls bellow the image, and the image itself, in a LinearLayout solved the problem without the need to query in advance the image size (SDK is 14).

Comment: Thanks.  The ImageView is part of a RelativeLayout at the moment.  I don't really like the way it came out in the end so I might change it to a LinearLayout when I revisit it.  It would be nice to get rid of the double access to the image without having to store all the image dimensions in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to notify the ListView to redraw itself. This is expensive and you should try to avoid it. It will also likely cause frustration with the user as the scroll position keeps changing. I would recommend trying to find an ideal ImageView size and use that to lock the row heights/widths so dynamic content does cause these issues.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

```
arrayAdapter.notfityDataSetChanged();
```

That should do it.

Comment: Calling arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); doesn't fix the issue.

It just spawns an infinite loop.

Comment: Where did you call it from? I believe you want to call it from the onPostExecute method of your asynctask.

Comment: That's exactly where I called it from.  That makes the list refresh and all the views are regenerated so it calls itself again so the list refreshes all items so it calls the async again so it list etc. It does not fix the fact that the ListView itself is the wrong size. I'll put some images up.

Comment: Ahh yeah you need to re use your views. Check into the ViewHolder pattern. You will also need to keep your downloaded images in an lrucache. There are quite a few articles detailing this entire process which is bit more than the scope of your original question.

Comment: I am using ViewHolders and reusing Views already.  Have a look at the images I just added to the question to see what the problem is.

Comment: Here is the developer article about this from Google. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html?m=1

Comment: That doesn't seem to cover why the ListView isn't the right size.  I'm already using an asynctask to load the images and as long as there's enough content to fill the screen, it works fine.  It's only with these tiny pages that this issue occurs.  Given that calling ListView.requestRelayout() from onListItemClick fixes the layout I guess I just need to figure out some nice way to call that but only when there's very small amounts of content, but after the images have loaded?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't reliably fix it either.  I wish the ListView would just Match_Parent like it's supposed to.

Comment: If you follow that guide you should be able to call notifyDatasetChanged() without it redownloading all the images again as they will be in the LRU cache. The problem is that you are changing the views after they are drawn. ListView is working as intended in my opinion. It does not resize rows until they are instructed to be redrawn. This is all part of the optimizations to improve scroll speed.

This will still be really wasteful of system resources. Try a LinearLayout wrapped in a ScrollView instead.

Comment: If I went with a LinearLayout in a scrollView the device would have to hold all elements in memory at the same time?  That might not work for some of the more complicated pages I have. However, given that it's the fact that the rows are resizing and I have all the images on disk, if I read the dimensions of each image and store them in the database (where I've got only the filename at the moment) I should be able to size the ImageView before loading the image into it, right?

Comment: Well, based on the discussions here, I went and fixed the height and width of the ImageView in the layout and now the ListView is the correct size!  I'll have to make it more intelligent and use the actual dimensions of the image at some point but thanks heaps for helping me work through this one @tencent !  That article you linked to will help resolve another issue that's popped up now.

Comment: Glad to help, listview + images is not an easy thing to implement. I just went through a lot of pain myself and I am still having problems due to the AsyncTasks only updating a few rows at a time. Its not a big deal in a ListView but in a GridView it gets pretty discouraging to keep poking it.